# Clear/Standard name for a Unit Range [0->1]

Tags: math, range, naming

I'm writing a Range class at the moment and I'm looking for a good name for the common range [0->1]. If it was a vector of length 1, I would call it a Unit vector. Is there a clear name to give this range/interval? Possibly a *Unit Range*?

Comment: Can you give an example use for the name you seek?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closed range between [0,1] is typically called the [closed unit interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnitInterval.html).  If you do not include the endpoints it would be the open unit interval.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for Interval, as it sounds better than 'Unit Range'  :)

Comment: I like Unit Range as (In my mind) it is clearer. Interval I find to be used predominately by mathematicians and also is more used by me in relation to time? @SurDim can you post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: What about frequency perhaps?

Comment: @leppie I'm more talking about the generic range 0->1 rather than anything specific implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

How about *Normal Range*?

Comment: I used to use the term normal, but it is technically incorrect. Here's the definition of a one dimensional normal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number. My idea of normal came from vector maths, but surface normals describe the tangent to a plane, it's a side effect that they are unit length