# Name for [-1.0, 1.0] range

Tags: math, naming

I am in the process of putting together a small library that requires the use of [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic).

As a part a part of this I am intending to implement two specialised cases of floating point types that are clamped to the [0.0, 1.0] and [-1.0, 1.0].

In terms of naming the [0.0, 1.0] range I found the following two questions that seemed quite helpful:

- [Question
  1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515311/how-to-name-value-with-range-of-0-0-to-1-0)
- [Question
  2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672860/clear-standard-name-for-a-unit-range-0-1)

But I am struggling to find a a way of naming/expressing the [-1.0, 1.0] range. I think part of this is related to the way search engines treat the negation sign on numbers, but it could just be that it has no special name.

**Is there a special name for this range or a reasonably short way of describing it that would be suitable for use in a type name?**

I did also consider asking this on mathematics, but as I am primarily a programmer and have a slight aversion to maths, I felt more confident asking here first in case I got bombarded with terminology and equations I didn't understand.

I find it odd that certain sequences/categories of numbers have special names (e.g. fibonacci sequence, mersenne primes) but such important ranges seemingly do not.

Answer (score 1):

Since [0.0, 1.0] is "normalized", [-1.0, 1.0] could be called "bipolar normalized".

Answer (score 1):

[0,1] is usually called the unit interval, but that is besides the point. If you construct some over-the-top name for every interval you want to use, you'll just confuse people. The closed interval from -1 to 1 represented by [-1,1] is most often referred to as " *the closed interval from [-1,1]* " because that is simply the most direct way to formalize it. You could also call it "range of tanh" or "vertex of quiver in homotopy" but these are more confusing realizations than anything.

For a type or object name, I would simply go with `closed_interv_neg1_to_1` or similar for whatever naming convention you are following.